# Upgrade drupal using drush: Failed to check available update

Tags: 7, drush, upgrading

I am trying to upgrade Drupal from 7.14 to 7.18 using `drush up` command.

Nothing gets updated and I see a bunch of failed warnings:

```
Failed to check available update data for CCK.
Failed to check available update data for CKEditor.  
...
Failed to get available update data for 51 projects.
```

I can however download modules using `drush dl module_name`
All commands are run as root.

Comment: any useful error messages from `drush up -d` (-d is for debug)?

Comment: Is Update module enabled? Are there any strange errors in Status Report, like HTTP Requests failing?

Answer (score 2):

As tenken suggested, you might try adding `-d` for debug to your drush command or `-v` for verbose.

Beyond that, I suggest trying to set $conf['update_max_fetch_time'] to a higher value (I usually set it to 360). It sounds like you may be running into an issue where [fetching the update information is exceeding the timeout](http://drupal.org/node/952394).

Comment: I dont have FTP access my my server, I do everything using SSH. I increased the timeout from 5 to 360 seconds as recommended in `modules/update/update.module` as well as `drush vset update_max_fetch_time 360`. Next I ran `drush up -d` but I still get warning, here a pastie: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=wZzdYp1d

Comment: Your paste makes it look like your Drupal site is unable to connect to the update server on Drupal.org - see where the paste starts saying "Failed to check available update data " for every module. Try checking direct access from your server to eg http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x via curl or wget.